# Has there been an update to C# on Visual Studio or is it just my IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I logged onto my Visual Studio and started to make some unit tests for a project and I noticed that in order to make an instance of a class from another project (my main project) I have to add the the namespace before the class. It wasn't like this yesterday. It's kind of bugging me. So was there an update overnight or did I change something in my IDE?

```
var foo = new Something.Something(); // <-- This is what I have to do now in projects
var foo = new Something(); // <-- This is what I was doing for the past year
```

If it is just me could you tell me how to fix this.

```
        var g1 = new GradeBook.GradeBook();
        var g2 = g1;

        g1 = new GradeBook.GradeBook();
        g1.Name = "Jakub's GradeBook";
        Assert.AreEqual(g1.Name, g2.Name);
```

If I get rid of the `GradeBook` namespace the compiler throws out an error.

```
        var g1 = new GradeBook();
        var g2 = g1;

        g1 = new GradeBook();
        g1.Name = "Jakub's GradeBook";
        Assert.AreEqual(g1.Name, g2.Name);
```

When I add a using directive it still throws out errors - `missing reference in file`

Comment: We need a [mcve] before we can offer any advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Here are some screenshots @Amy

Comment: As the tooltip suggests, add the missing namespace...  See my answer below.

Comment: Please don't upload images of code.  Copy the actual code.  See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Sorry. And yeh I tried and it didn't work

Comment: clean your solution, rebuild. close/repoen VS. Use Alt+Enter to fix it. - all this did not solve it?

Comment: Nope it fixes it by adding the namespace e.g.  `GradeBook.GradeBook();`

Comment: What is the name of the class inside of which you are writing this code?

Comment: Its allways helpful if you provide the error you are getting. Because that error usually tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The error is just `missing reference in file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that both your class and its namespace have the same name.
Making the compiler unable to tell which one you are referring to. Hence you'll get an error similiar like `GradeBook is a namespace but is used like a type`

It should work if you write

```
var x = new GradeBook.GradeBook();
```

You can work arround this by using an alias for your using like so:

```
using G=GradeBook;
```

And then write

```
var x = new G.GradeBook();
```

But I`d recommend you to reevaluate your naming.

Comment: Yes I will have to work on that :) I'm a noob. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I think you are missing the namespace to your project containing `Something()` class.

Import your project as follow:

```
using Something;
```

And then you will be able to use your class without having to add the project name before it, like:

```
var foo = new Something();
```

Comment: Nope I tried it. Still throws an error. The using directive gets marked as  unused @monsterjie_za